# Differentiation of a parametric curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose there is a curve whose parametric form can be represented by $\gamma(t)$, where $t$ is a parameter. Let $\gamma(t) =( \gamma_1(t) , \gamma_2(t) , ... , \gamma_n(t) )$ be $n$ components of this parametric curve. When we differentiate $\gamma(t)$ , we differentiate all of its components, i.e. ,  $\gamma '(t) = ( \gamma_1'(t) , \gamma_2'(t) , ... , \gamma_n'(t) )$.

Why do we do so?

Answer (score 1):

I really like this question.

The total derivative, when it exists, of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ at a point $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined to be its "linear approximation at $\vec{x}$", i.e. a linear map $L:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ such that
$$
0=\lim_{\vec{h}\rightarrow 0}\ \frac{f(\vec{x}+\vec{h})-f(\vec{x})-L(\vec{h})}{|\vec{h}|}.
$$
Let us denote this linear map $L$ by "$df(\vec{x})$".
The projection map $\pi_i:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ sending $(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ to $x_i$ is linear, so its derivative anywhere is itself. By the chain rule, we have
\begin{align*}
d(\pi_i\circ f)(\vec{x})&=d\pi_i(f(\vec{x}))\circ df(\vec{x})\\
&=\pi_i\circ df(\vec{x}).
\end{align*}
In other words, the $i^\text{th}$ component function of the derivative of $f$ equals the derivative of the $i^\text{th}$ component function of $f$. The statement you're looking for is the case $n=1$. So the answer to your question is, "Because projection is linear."